# sql connectionstring and pooling=true

Tags: c#, database-connection, connection-string

in an application with high requests, some store procedures are very slow time to time. after checking all things, DB team is saying every thing in SQL is ok and the code has problems.
I figure out, connectionstring to the sql might has some problem. this is the current connection string to sql in appsetting.json that i set:

```
"Connection": "Data Source=X;Initial Catalog=X;user id=X;password=X;MultipleActiveResultSets=True",
```

this is what i want to change:

```
"Connection": "Data Source=X;Initial Catalog=X;Persist Security Info=True;user id=X;password=X;Connect Timeout=10000;Pooling=True; Min Pool Size=200;Max Pool Size=2000",
```

but all other applications are using database and the same procedures. does having `Min pool` make some problems to increase `the response time for procedures`?

Comment: Connecting to what? This is not related to the <sql> _language_.

Comment: connectionstring to sql. the above is my connectionstring i set in appsetting @jarlh

Comment: jarlh's point is that SQL is "structured query language", not a specific DBMS. You can use SQL to talk to MySql, PostgreSQL, Microsoft SQL Server, Google Big Query, Microsoft Access, and many others. The [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql) for the SQL tag states: _"If your question relates solely to a specific DBMS (uses specific extensions/features), use that DBMS's tag instead."_ and, given your quesiton is about the connection string and connection pooling, I expect it does solely relate to a specific DBMS.

Comment: Those connection pool sizes look too large, especially the minimum.  Each requires a lot of overhead.  Some RDBMSes don't even allow such high values!  You should start smaller and then increase only when needed.  See https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/320217/optimize-the-number-of-connections-of-the-connection-pool-and-mysql

Comment: Pooling will not solve the slow response time.  Database may be fragmented and needs to be defrag.  Database may be very large and using all the available memory on machine and you need more memory.  A database should be put on a machine that is the fastest available, with the most number of cores, and contains as much memory that is avaiable.

Comment: `Pooling=True` is the default, and if you are having trouble with pooling then you should check you are disposing your connections properly. Such a large minimum pool is pointless, it's just going to overload your server with unused connections. None of this is likely to fix your issues, which we can't tell because you haven't provided any relevant code.